# ListView Xamarin.forms dynamically load image from ItemSource with ImageResource

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms

I have an issue in my xamarin.Forms application in MVVM. I have a ListView and I want to show an image in the ItemTemplate. To do that I have created a ImageRessource Class:

```
[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource($"CoPro.Assets.{Source}");

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml of my ListView:

```
 <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Series}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{images:ImageResource image.jpg}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource UsualLabelTemplate}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Besides, I have set "images" by this namespace :xmlns:images="clr-namespace:CoPro.Assets"

Like this, my ListView show the same picture for every "Series" Item. 
For each Item there is a string property with the path of the image.
How can I show image of each Item, please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not directly use FileImageSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution. I had to use Source property from Image tag:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Series}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                           
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                                              />
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource UsualLabelTemplate}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

The solution was to use a Converter, and Source property contained a string. This string is sent into parameter in my converter like this:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return ImageSource.FromResource($"CoPro.Assets.{value}"); 
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }  
    }
```

in this code "$"CoPro.Assets" is the path where is my image File.

Thanks for your help